# How to call a usercontrols event from another user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have user control A, and user control B. How can I register an event in user control B, so that it gets fired?. It seems like control A is doing something and not letting the event in user control B get fired.

```
MyControlA.ascx.cs


MyControlB.ascx.cs

  //need to fire this when checkbox of this user control is clicked.
  //but it seems MyControlA.ascx.cs which uses user control B is causing something that
  //does not allow this to get fired.
  protected void myCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            //SOME CODE HERE
   }
```

Comment: Is your event handler in MyControlB? And is the checkbox on MyControlB?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the set up - but MyControlA registers it

Comment: MyControlA registers the event to the handler? Correct? If so, can you post how you register the handler?

Comment: it registers it like this <%@ Register Src="MyControlB.ascx" TagName="ControlB" TagPrefix="uc2" %>

Comment: Huh? How does this relate to `myCheckBox_CheckedChanged`?

Comment: when the control MyControlA is rendered, it renders MyControlA and MyControlB, but when I click on the checkbox, it is not firing MyControlB's OnCheckChanged although it does pass by the Page_Load, for some reason ignores the event handler.. is there a way to let MyControlA know that MyControlB has an event that needs to fire when called?

Comment: Events are not supposed to be fired from outside the owning class, they were specially designed for that. You can give control B a method that can be called by A and that makes B fire the event itself. But I'm not sure why you should want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register to the event of user control B in the webpage that uses it.
Register to the event of user control A in the webpage that uses it.

Then, when control A fires the event, your webpage will catch it.  Once it catches it, fire the event in user control B.

Use your webpage as the middle class that combines both user controls together.